# How to maintain equal spacing between font icons in a navigation bar when texts with font-icons are used as link?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This is my code for a navigation bar:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #495057;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #adb5bd;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>test</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>123test123</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12345test12345</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12test12</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>1test1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here, I've used font icons along with link name. But, in practical all the link names are not of equal length. That's why, with the above code, the output looks very bad as the spaces after each font icons are not equal. Though the `padding-right` of each links are 20px, and all of them are equally spaced, but for variable size of the link names, the font icons are not equally spaced.

My desired output is: all the font icons will be in equal space whatever be the space between the link names. That will be something like below image:

[image]

I've failed to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS flexbox, and use `justify-content:space-between(around)` in your `ul`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #495057;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #adb5bd;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>test</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>123test123</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12345test12345</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12test12</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>1test1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As you wish, but don't choose on who answer first, but which answer is better fit for your question. (just a note, my answer has a cleaner code ;) )

Answer (score 4):

Updated the following style

```
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #495057;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #adb5bd;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>test</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>123test123</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12345test12345</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12test12</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>1test1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `space-evenly`is not supported in IE and EDGE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: Update 2023: IE is gone but EDGE does now support it.

https://caniuse.com/?search=justify-content

Comment: Thanks for the update @ShaneMuirhead . Please upvote to help other people know that this is a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #495057;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #adb5bd;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>test</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>123test123</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12345test12345</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>12test12</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-font"></i>
        <div>1test1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit the following:

```
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;    
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  
}
```

Comment: If you actually look at the other two answers, they've coded it differently to as I have.

Comment: Thanks, @billy.farroll, your attempt was also perfect. All 3 answers should have to be accepted. But I had to choose one.